# Pinia type inference broken when my computed properties are in the code, when I remove them, type inference works again

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, pinia

If I remove all of the computed(()=>{}) definitions, i get back type inference. When I put them back, the store reverts back to type any. I loose all ts help in other files.

I tried removing the properties, that solves the problem but I obviously need those for my app to function.

```
import { useVuelidate } from "@vuelidate/core";
import { cloneDeep, toNumber } from "lodash";
import { getNestedObjectValue, setNestedObjectValue } from "./helpers";
export const useApplicationStore = defineStore(
  "application",
  () =\> {
    // ? Questionnaire Definitions

let questionnaires = reactive(\[
  {
    id: "petitionPartOne",
    label: "Petition Part One",
    progress: {
      completed: false,
      percentage: 0,
    },
    navigation: {
      history: \[\],
    },
    questionCategories: petitionPartOneCategories(),
  },
\]);

//#region Data Definitions

// function dynamicProperty(path) {
//   return computed({
//     get: () =\> getNestedObjectValue($customerData, path),
//     set: (value) =\> setNestedObjectValue($customerData, path, value),
//   });
// }
let $settings = reactive({
  startingQuestionnaireId: "petitionPartOne",
});

let $data = reactive({
  activeQuestionnaireID: "",
  activeQuestionnaireCategoryID: "",
  activeQuestionID: "",
});

let $customerData = reactive({
  sponsor: {
    fullName: {
      first: "",
      middle: "",
      last: "",
    },
  },
  beneficiary: {
    fullName: {
      first: "",
      middle: "",
      last: "",
    },
  },
});
//#endregion Data Definitions

//#region Computed Getters
let questionCompletionStatusInjection = (questionId) =\> {
  return activeQuestionnaire.value!.questionCategories;
};

const activeQuestionnaire = computed(() =\> {
  return questionnaires.find(
    (questionnaire) =\> questionnaire.id === $data.activeQuestionnaireID
  );
});
const activeQuestionnaireQuestionCategories = computed(() =\> {
  if (!activeQuestionnaire.value) {
    return "Active Questionnaire Is Unset";
  }
  return activeQuestionnaire.value.questionCategories;
});
const activeQuestionnaireProgress = computed(() =\> {
  if (!activeQuestionnaire.value) {
    return "Active Questionnaire Is Unset";
  }
  return activeQuestionnaire.value.progress;
});
const activeQuestionnaireCategory = computed(() =\> {
  if (!activeQuestionnaire.value) {
    return "Active Questionnaire Is Unset";
  } else if (activeQuestionnaire.value) {
    return activeQuestionnaire.value.questionCategories.find(
      (category) =\> category.id === $data.activeQuestionnaireCategoryID
    );
  }
});
const activeQuestionnaireCategoryIndex = computed(() =\> {
  if (!activeQuestionnaire.value) {
    return "Active Questionnaire Is Unset";
  } else if (activeQuestionnaire.value) {
    return activeQuestionnaire.value.questionCategories.findIndex(
      (category) =\> category.id === $data.activeQuestionnaireCategoryID
    );
  }
});
const onFinalQuestionnaireCategory = computed(() =\> {
  if (!activeQuestionnaire.value) {
    return "Active Questionnaire Is Unset";
  } else if (activeQuestionnaire.value) {
    return (
      activeQuestionnaireCategoryIndex.value ===
      activeQuestionnaire.value.questionCategories.length - 1
    );
  }
});
const activeQuestion = computed(() =\> {
  if (typeof activeQuestionnaireCategory.value !== "string") {
    return activeQuestionnaireCategory.value!.questions.find(
      (question) =\> question.id === $data.activeQuestionID
    );
  } else {
    return "Active Questionnaire Category Is Unset";
  }
});
const nextQuestion = computed(() =\> {
  if (typeof activeQuestionnaireCategory.value !== "string") {
    let nextQuestionIndex =
      activeQuestionnaireCategory.value!.questions.findIndex(
        (question) =\> question.id === $data.activeQuestionID
      );
    if (
      activeQuestionnaireCategory.value!.questions.length ===
      nextQuestionIndex + 1
    ) {
      return "End of Questionnaire";
    }
    return activeQuestionnaireCategory.value!.questions\[
      nextQuestionIndex + 1
    \];
  } else {
    return "Active Questionnaire Category Is Unset";
  }
});
//#endregion Computed Getters

//#region Actions

let setActiveQuestionnaire = (questionnaireId) =\> {
  $data.activeQuestionnaireID = questionnaireId;
};
let setActiveQuestionnaireCategoryToFirstCategoryInQuestionnaire = () =\> {
  if (typeof activeQuestionnaireQuestionCategories.value\[0\] !== "string") {
    $data.activeQuestionnaireCategoryID =
      activeQuestionnaireQuestionCategories.value\[0\].id;
  }
};
let setActiveQuestionnaireCategoryToNextCategoryInQuestionnaire = () =\> {
  if (typeof activeQuestionnaireQuestionCategories.value\[0\] !== "string") {
    $data.activeQuestionnaireCategoryID =
      activeQuestionnaireQuestionCategories.value\[
        toNumber(activeQuestionnaireCategoryIndex.value!) + 1
      \].id;
  }
};
let setActiveQuestionIDToFirstQuestionInActiveQuestionnaireCategory =
  () =\> {
    if (
      typeof activeQuestionnaireCategory.value !== "string" &&
      typeof activeQuestionnaireCategory.value !== "undefined"
    ) {
      $data.activeQuestionID =
        activeQuestionnaireCategory.value.questions\[0\].id;
    } else {
      console.error("Active Questionnaire Category is undefined");
    }
  };
let setActiveQuestion = (questionId) =\> {
  $data.activeQuestionID = questionId;
};

let navigateToNextQuestion = () =\> {
  if (nextQuestion.value === "Active Questionnaire Category Is Unset") {
    console.error("Next Question is undefined");
    return;
  }
  // @ts-ignore
  if (nextQuestion.value == "End of Questionnaire") {
    // TODO - We need to check if there is other categories in the questionnaire
    // TODO - If there is, set the activeQuestionnaireCategory to the first one
    if (!onFinalQuestionnaireCategory.value) {
      setActiveQuestionnaireCategoryToNextCategoryInQuestionnaire();
      setActiveQuestionIDToFirstQuestionInActiveQuestionnaireCategory();
    }
  } else {
    setActiveQuestion(activeQuestion.value!.nextQuestion());
  }
};

let initialize = () =\> {
  // ! If none in memory, set active questionnaire to starting questionnaire
  // ! If there is one in memory, set active questionnaire to that one
  if (!$data.activeQuestionnaireID) {
    setActiveQuestionnaire($settings.startingQuestionnaireId);
    // TODO - Now we need to get the activeQuestionnaire so we can explore its questionCategories
    // ? You can get the active questionnaire by calling activeQuestionnaire.value
    // TODO - Of the categories lets get the first one then set that as the activeQuestionnaireCategory by its id
    setActiveQuestionnaireCategoryToFirstCategoryInQuestionnaire();
    // TODO - Now we need to set the activeQuestion to the first question in the activeQuestionnaireCategory
    setActiveQuestionIDToFirstQuestionInActiveQuestionnaireCategory();
  }
};
//#endregion Actions

// initialize();

//#region Return Object
return {
  $settings,
  $data,
  $customerData,
  activeQuestionnaireProgress,
  activeQuestionnaireQuestionCategories,
  activeQuestionnaire,
  activeQuestion,
  questionnaires,

  activeQuestionnaireCategory,
  nextQuestion,
  activeQuestionnaireCategoryIndex,
  onFinalQuestionnaireCategory,

  setActiveQuestionnaire,
  setActiveQuestionnaireCategoryToFirstCategoryInQuestionnaire,
  setActiveQuestionIDToFirstQuestionInActiveQuestionnaireCategory,
  // ? Questionnaire Navigation Actions
  navigateToNextQuestion,
  initialize,
};
//#endregion Return Object
  },
  {
    persist: true,
  }
);
if (import.meta.hot) {
  import.meta.hot.accept(acceptHMRUpdate(useApplicationStore, import.meta.hot));}
```

If I remove all of the computed(()=>{}) definitions, i get back type inference. When I put them back, the store reverts back to type any. I loose all ts help in other files.

I tried removing the properties, that solves the problem but I obviously need those for my app to function.

Comment: What `=\>` does?

Comment: Stack overflow added that to the code for some reason when I uploaded this.

Comment: Please ignore all the \

Comment: "I loose all ts help in other files" - do you mean you get this in IDE? Then it's the problem that is specific to IDE, which you didn't mention

Comment: We dont know that for sure.